# Firefox: Search history for content

Tags: firefox

I want to find the URL that I visited yesterday. I know the content of the page included the words `foo` and `bar`.

Can I find the page using Firefox' history search?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Can I find the page using Firefox' history search?

> I know the content of the page included the words `foo` and `bar`.

No. This is because the history only includes the URL itself.

It knows nothing about the contents of the page pointed to by the URL.

Comment: But is not pages' content downloaded onto the hard drive? If it is, then it has to be possible to search it.

Comment: @RusI If it is a recent visit the page may still be in the Firefox cache (this depends on your cache settings) , but the cache is not searchable from the History page.

Comment: I wonder if it is security related feature or what? It would awfully useful to be able to search for a keyword in visited pages content.

Comment: @RusI [I want to view Firefox cache. | Firefox Support Forum | Mozilla Support](https://support.mozilla.org/bm/questions/1220435), but discussion on that needs a new question (discussion desn't belong here).